# State generated too long by OpenId connect for Azure AD external login

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have implemented a login flow using OpenID, that redirects more than one server (**My Application-> Identity Server-> Azure AD**) to authenticate users. **My Application** and **Identity server** both are using OpenId for login.
In My login flow, the user will be redirected from **My Application** to the **Identity Server** with redirect URI, then **Identity Server** redirects to **Azure AD**. In this request, the `state` property is so large, so Azure AD can't accept and shows the request query too long.

I have to reduce the length of the `state` property on the Azure AD login request. Can you suggest how to customize the `state` generation in my application with OpenId. Is this possible to generate and validate the `state` manually?

Answer (score 0):

If a **state** parameter is included in the request, the same value should appear in the response. The app should verify that the state values in the request and response are identical.

```html
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=form_post
&scope=openid
&state=12345     // Any value, provided by your app
&nonce=678910
```

STATE : A value included in the request that also will be returned in the token response. It can be a string of any content you want. A randomly generated unique value typically is used to prevent cross-site request forgery attacks. The state also is used to encode information about the user's state in the app before the authentication request occurred, such as the page or view the user was on.

Reference : Microsoft identity platform and OpenID Connect protocol - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs