# Requested query string is too long when Azure Ad External Login configured using OpenIddict

Tags: openiddict

I am trying to add Azure AD External Login (user registration, consent and login) to OpenIddict server.

ASP.NET CORE MVC ( Client ) -> Auth Server ( OpenIdDict) -> Microsoft login ( Request query string is too long)

Is it because of State ? [State generated too long by OpenId connect for Azure AD external login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68887448/state-generated-too-long-by-openid-connect-for-azure-ad-external-login)

If yes, is there a way to generate short state using OpenIddict?

In the Auth server, I added External Login

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
{
microsoftOptions.ClientId = ClientId;
microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
}
```

Error Request : https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fauthserver%3APortNum%2Fsignin-microsoft&response_type=code&prompt=login&scope=openid%20profile%20email&response_mode=form_post&nonce=638162890685421703.MjE4YzhmMTkMC00OWU0LTk4NDQtZDA3NWVmZTM3ODMyNGQ2ZjBhYWMtOTBjZC00N2NkLTg0MjUtZTM4MzI5OGYxYjVl&state=CfDJ8BVMooZUnqJBtvjaXHnb-8CwCtmqtnkKIRNB1zaLpisWh30tUDztCQ3-ReG_V9HoWvupI7_EbPSqhp8khtRjzxPsOh40B2C4ah9zY41XKJyVF9DlmSEClun8sNXKekNXErVsMriga3fD_vF4jbIQ2tuvEM09hFC_-9TkcZxusyttEJ4XxAKomHC9mWGDQ2bbBhzBMK8Esu0aNfkP7Q7Oqn8i8LTkO9xEJuoZXClZzoHhfJlgKN2dPv3By1qe3h6tZZhm7Aq-7FLGUGxVkSI9yQT9dyDEvMAZmyi5uNHSHqm7Y4xRkvhutLybGndkoQfAIan5lrxfVhxRY-WVYmFBUnaRugNgrjL41LixyQNRuG0gA__mrZCb3G7gOtC-XVn9rOavPH9YhvpHc50DZZC9c1mNcwrbBhWbWQXsWA_X01l61c9fWhGRcB62o4NXpSuBFqNwbQlpU2BTrdsve42f-M3pIHDGr-XxdrMKOhVEXxt7GXwCna0JGemqeH-J-JyPUfpX91EzOb2sKUCnaipZu8w-OSK63mhb7Cott6YiBRw6wYqpj6Wpj9KVWqE5dkQg2EHUjViFi2g5ZkGjd4hEVMi6a-lwe7JHre6DxG9ymWnYvgoZDGEpnNFptK5JUZICUMV90qRyhufBmLczNqJKNpIpKtp9m_jXkyAfSpoPXJGYYTBBfbFFvcpWovFgMLGoUPD_B04V_Wu2dN7uOGzgDJD52UPnOMBeP-yAIAIyhzTqbMPjwJnit1-HAtyO4pGnSZvxc1jm_PdmTVgfQjQpctewrdULk4V4Ca_mxPRUqi4gqc_g7j1UbW9o9stqtaWbRDyNKndEAOljVFqjUKQxJu4_gTNDQUvr7hCgXRX9onPuTpVbkySxhQ2lCQvpEZH8Cv8J8bID-b5vHNvfWIAX26vP7nJ8FXmx2nggVhzXD7vV3X2bVFJZUqaUOgL2g6eUwQ9btW0C_eP3hf0q-Nc84JB447Ew2fZ74FRGyRA8rUiz5AG3OtKykxUFdvy2xxIIvIH2gb54XwPgk9uOAkNwLXJnbTsllZ2REcqvz8D-a8FZs0wPwlvuWxSnCw4phknf2TQRJs95wwtSqJXGqXnbnxpC4rk7nHVRR0zxHnLqZQODAy2wFQjEFgYxd-Fshrt4kIF1Orts07NjOmcAIpIReIpsUAM28R13mFOa_XmD6cNvp3GDXFmWob0sj_TS-3weY_NPMiMfv7Rn6rPZRCCaxYLMIlnMHEp3wNalyz7p8Kdal50J0vXW2Eh7NSMEJ7NdF-QFNqIj4yVND2wKCObrrZtcNUby_nMIvc3lYfvhHDiklSuR1s1yZcmw-FPdUUBJw5FYr-idi7JFg3W00QH4yppTeJfUZ98EWiNrTbaCsCTAsHyWZRQYSbQHkLPsM_f3AHcWA72lEaGxEtX1Fsl9m84Ejn2AbUYzYia8AVlRv6aR6l3SidKLt-5sNVfsCGEwMTXd0dS8Rp79jsOQp5Wd2xdyMUCQUJZ7kSMHMBmc0BzP1P2g0TVSrxWkHrzT2p6tRK4KgwlKlgqxhiJ_crrhFCd9ZAGvSLvwfUK8_EmKZLfZ8TeVJ2QxHPiInnTR7yzanCeMn1rBtBeSeQPfqeUpLBxNQmais-asWK-5ENduZyG4WshdE9Xxwz0qV4eX4bMdg3Jzg9thNXX-mkc17slHtE-_F70TW-6tB-V47378vmV-Ne5eASZhPDAusZrSDuvC9bH_v-shzoOQyTwtu_nVDxD6FEa3-RUj4F6Bua1XyKy0pXFwR2oFsUCR2knFYEX1m7SJyhfkqG99yY1fLjW3bEDAVhUFsObEy0jPZEWctMDvBlkF00i3ooSmOE8mRuGVFD30_p8LJ-Fk93QyJnw0satZi_ffNF7fpa9K3VePvtXdLCkGf3B6AuG-vFrSnMtudYdRoojJo6doM2Ed81XqPMYba_51oqMSdIB6MfbvKNS4s8M06l37-hsUU9ncxMDQPW6eiEVHpLzGZIhBHjsnU6otAjTqm3-pJ_m1a3R8TqwrfpyDZCU3wL-fTwyBU211VzmepTCtK3RHf3gds1rRH0uoiBcdRhZ6YVy_kRSLhLPCr5By5lPl645nlg5CEHZS9320soNupUB0VFgGvvSeWbW5pUbK2T_Eekuxahv_v5Fsq-63O6qk3iFxAhuU1hWA6CnxxGXVrIX1CJs0RUUB7JRhKVwUUf8CgDlQYobFxUygR1_z4NggkVa-YLfXwTaxC3LoB4oJrjiQ9UKH9Q8zODBPmPuhM6ZbXNkm_gFWVQQMlcQcueMwL_q3c5zQEcxblaMBOnxTRvzdlXGo7dG9J-_qy7KOZZlMkZWorKgB004etDOl_J7l0ZykDSk2iwpMPF7vzKz-TAghzyk27xq1SkhBu09fI82eyW_HoYI-tfqHhq4AS4phdKl_cPV5sj4cUyp-MLIzPXQnGPJ8hjw8vYJo6LZRqit7fMl9G9c9Yqt0WZXzOvafi2acVEnrerGMMzxI46GlT8t6lX6aLCcy9BDq56zYMnAZmvwMA00w53oyg_rn9xNatThFujcqMnXVdTs09CeqvNuRYZl3FwCUr_v5MZY3fuzPuwInzdJ0bHLmuccCvfs0Ks251pyx74IY51LYNCjjUUAwcvl8I2JnWJFeExdfRbamKXdakQp_kPhjLb8kCYw4cMVQ2YDNgXUmOqbLP6EeJMXp5M0sz--r8VtNHu_OBvajkfSNauN0X15yELr6WA0hKhp92Fms3JM9Z_-HqgMx8DAMoMU3u_QJIsGBvWHf5sfcLIsIGKqNe6Ak35fy0d7UFqg1WYfTAVg3WgrCAXbyCBh5VGR07Z5y1OhQqm5anBOyKncuyTz7ZesUNK00wEtaITBXaVnRZWjz5ZGliBEGN84G9I9_boyIoAptF7_Ci7K62GvRPLlx9vka3vTtM7Hlzz9wF5Lup436GzgFJqmn-VflpTSNov5j29PqsmZKaDcik3pWmAIHuzu1BRZ67QhWDg1AOLw0H10okmBAPvocUTiQCp6qp8N3dV27hmAiSYa3NdY4UfbxVHUMMx7J0oAgicjej0pGR6Mb2f-C5exQYKLKubLcZ8DX2O9N7b6lA5xETqv7OxFdHGS5dGMjsmTcc6yGPvqG4ukkNzj32_nF3sZ_8ErEQqDbxrJ6Ofm7v9vxh3aMjlXBpjFJseiwIyYgzzTM1m8CVfYc9lbNY18tTLLSOa_4MzcaQASHqm2Y1bzBgv0jIAzMV5C-bgq6kSNCOaPXAiaXqdRwDL1lIX8AjFSuaBMk3rhZNyURegkKDKN_KOp41QsHMRnMLzn61c6WoirZ9ud6hNOMOsZn-1T8NFS3sAO7nC9pIuPBNhCrmmE_1dylrk88OWLf1JWPBO8agezOIvNYmFMv7p8knN0GrfBJsVoBmfTY1REMNgn8IPlyZQXCosHBd-jHGrZ4yNH6ZsCArmPN90AAYTagNIkRgIL8_jV9c3A4eG4UekuuFqMp8wyFSoeLZwbk2em8gMRhMMHpt73DRru1HajW5EhxtQmi2074_cBiPWXuOLBEXKz8Os_-UfGyC3gRC2Z32O3779toj67_UgiFfu03qugrhJmg1iQTYhrB6KFlu1GVxAbvXjYBBX5r8wll77LS_P_qvvaQhEfAtrP7YgPEf_bEy12v5Iz7DLyVUVLO3IkbhxcnZaCwkZ57kN_Mt3hm01C5YDFNX4BmMSlCVy4TkcIaZRAtGZZ_sz0Ehxz2XL3vX1pdPj1O47ZR6FNMkNt6T8RRmxy59UtgBDXoNTQUjD6000fNfEYtAuZ6Uf-8S5sGB4C3w-JSEn3p9LLeFqvKjV6OVgej6K_VY617CohepKtuEMzQ_gI2_lEcUnpNSgO-wNfV9kZ0kra5IXH5ILYTKkwj3YL7jG5gx2H_iV_yywIozvQ2kkAQNjshDkLl3PecTFNX2fOoc1yVcPPKJ-UI-lHdPt-nk7-wEC3fhjzXiQym6m6RjyFwxd_MN85X8ylp_WR__0woQCPWlwJRinPyK1KM_DoT5LlSjXuR_0lbRJKnfUVMY6No42rjWbQhU2KNI16htLIsZpWX4uj3RoHn8PKeC05QXZ70_pQFQS1-JxgNc2SNMvSLBOLsMePc88v_7zcldJAkFUmu0oS1yIpcyRiM-7horxKv3qqK8jobwQpkxj-lB3xUZ_SV5tCTeuCOErEu5SfNQqVL3LMCcOpnG4hSAgY3eshZjRf8omE2FLPyDrLEQT2VARUsPpU9UQN3IJHyqdLQ&
x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&
x-client-ver=6.10.0.0

Comment: can you post a sample link that is to long? also which of the fields is the longest?

Comment: Here is the payload
client_id: Guid
response_type: code
redirect_uri: https://localhost:port/signin-microsoft
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read
code_challenge: nfVqXWBJ7826KcPigIPy6AzQdzXJHaJktj-OuNkg6A
code_challenge_method: S256
state: CfDJ8BVMooZUnqJBtvjaXHnb-8BSQfuyu9HwKaBTsDpCKV

State is the longest, I couldn't copy the entire state because it is 4400 characters

Comment: Something similar to AddOidcStateDataFormatterCache extension method in IdentityServer. https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/ui/login/external/#state-url-length-and-isecuredataformat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without authentication - ASP.NET CORE MVC client app will redirect users to Auth server along with client related payload - (returnurl, client id, redirect_url, scopes, code_challenge, state.. etc).

At Auth server, when you click on external login it will post client's returnUrl to ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs - (you will see this page after scaffolding - DefaultUI middleware for Identity).

MicrosoftAccount/OpenIdConnect middleware considered client's returnUrl and payload from auth server to generate state which resulted in long request query string.

I have resolved this issue by updating returnUrl in ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs to empty.

```
returnUrl = string.Empty;
// Request a redirect to the external login provider.
var redirectUrl = Url.Page("./ExternalLogin", pageHandler: "Callback", values: new { returnUrl });
var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
```

You will be redirected to Azure AD without any errors.

After successful azure login, basic information like profile, email will be sent to auth server for user registration.

When you click on Register, in the background your information will be stored in the db, redirected to client and back to auth server for consent.
After you grant permissions or consent, it will redirect you to client app as authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

If you see [this](https://damienbod.com/2019/05/17/updating-microsoft-account-logins-in-asp-net-core-with-openid-connect-and-azure-active-directory/) blog post, then it says:

*The AddOpenIdConnect OIDC extension method should now be used instead of the AddMicrosoftAccount method.*

So, I would recommend that you try to use AddOpenIdConnect  instead.

Comment: I am trying out AddOpenIdConnect instead of AddMicrosoftAccount

Comment: I got the same error - Requested query string is too long. Do you think state is preserving previous call ExternalLogin?returnUrl=includes openid connect parameters from ASP.NET CORE MVC ( Client )

Comment: can you post a bit more about how you configure OpenIDConnect? Usually it should not be that long.

Comment: Similar to https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/blob/dev/samples/Velusia/Velusia.Server/Startup.cs

Comment: Please post your full request URL that fails

Comment: Another example which explains what I am trying to do - https://damienbod.com/2022/05/02/implement-an-openiddict-identity-provider-using-asp-net-core-identity-with-keycloak-federation/    Instead of angular and keycloak - I am using asp.net core mvc and AzureAd